# Single data point that contains commas in Excel worksheet gets converted to NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, data-conversion

I am trying to upload the following table from an Excel worksheet into SQL Server (keep in mind this is an Excel workbook and NOT a csv file). When I upload the below data, SQL Server cannot show rows 2 and 4 as varchar. The data gets converted to NULL.

| color | F2 |
| --- | --- |
| red | 1,4,6 |
| blue | NULL |
| green | 3,5 |
| orange | NULL |

I expect SQL to show the table exactly as is but am instead getting the following output:

| color | F2 |
| --- | --- |
| red | 1 |
| blue | NULL |
| green | 3 |
| orange | NULL |

How do I get the data to convert properly? I have already tried explicitly changing the data types to varchar(255), varchar(max), float, and bigint, but the values still get converted to NULL.

I also tried converting the commas to another type of delimiter (e.g. hyphens and slashes) but still the same issue.

Comment: What technique are you using to "upload" the data?

Comment: As you have mixed numbers and strings in a column have you tried formatting the numbers as text? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-text-583160db-936b-4e52-bdff-6f1863518ba4

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I tried converting the data to 'text' in Excel but that still generated the NULL values. I have also tried using Import Wizard as well as tried using the following command to explicitly declare data types:


  CREATE TABLE test (
  color nvarchar(255),
  F2 nvarchar(255)
  );

Comment: Quoting site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Paul, I'm working on it. I will edit in a second.

@Martin, you're right converting to text actually does work. BUT I learned that you have to convert to 'text' and THEN paste the data, otherwise the value still shows as NULL. Originally, I tried converting the already pasted values to 'text' and still got NULL. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Importing mixed column data from excel to sql server is the hardest problem of them all, i'm pretty sure you misdeclared the bindings in the data import "wizard" and it still "guessed" that rows were numbers not strings

Comment: @PaulMaxwell and Dale - the screenshots were useful here. We can see in them that the numbers are right aligned so not formatted as text

Comment: I cannot see the images due to imgur.com being blocked. Reliance on third party sites is a problem for future as well.

Comment: @siggemannen, do you have a suggestion on which data type I should have declared in the bindings when importing the data into the import wizard? Martin's answer worked, just curious to see if there is another solution as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER-- Martin Smith gave the correct answer as follows:

You need to convert the data to data type 'text' in Excel. BUT you have to convert to 'text' and THEN paste the data, otherwise the value still shows as NULL. Originally, I tried converting the already pasted values to 'text' and still got NULL.

If re-pasting the data AFTER converting the Excel columns to text does not work, copy the data from Excel into Notepad or Notepad++, then recopy the data, and then repaste back into Excel. This will force the data to paste as 'text'. Repasting the data as 'values' did not work.